# is there a way I can chain dialog with luis

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to call a dialog from my luis intent.
But I am getting error. please check my code.It reaches the UserInteraction dialog but the control does not go to Getuserpurpose.It shows an error "my bot code is having an issue"

I tried debugging and I found out that the control transfers to Webapi config class after StartAsync Task.

```
[LuisIntent("Getfile")]
    public async Task GetfileIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Sure we can help you on that... ");
        //PromptDialog.Text(context, UserEnteredInfo, "can you please provide us with below info. " +
        //    "Purpose" + "Client name" + "Team Name");
        await context.PostAsync("But first i need to know the purpose ");
      //  Conversation.SendAsync(Activity, () => new UserInteraction());
       context.Call(new UserInteraction(),ResumeAfterFeedback);

    }
    private async Task ResumeAfterFeedback(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Prepared an email for you");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }


[Serializable]
public class UserInteraction : IDialog<object>
{
    protected string Purpose { get; set; }
    protected string ClientName { get; set; }
    protected string Teamname { get; set; }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Please enter the purpose");

       // context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        context.Wait(Getuserpurpose);

    }
    public async Task Getuserpurpose(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;
        this.Purpose = message.Text;
        await context.PostAsync("Now please tell me the client name");
        context.Wait(Getuserclient);

    }
```

Comment: Are you seeing any exceptions in the output window when you debug locally?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this out, and it does work as expected.

```
[LuisIntent("Getfile")]
    public async Task GetfileIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Sure we can help you on that... ");
        await context.PostAsync("But first i need to know the purpose ");
       context.Call(new UserInteraction(),ResumeAfterFeedback);

    }
    private async Task ResumeAfterFeedback(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var interactionResult = await result as UserInteraction;
        await context.PostAsync("Prepared an email for you");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class UserInteraction : IDialog<object>
    {
        protected string Purpose { get; set; }
        protected string ClientName { get; set; }
        protected string Teamname { get; set; }

        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Please enter the purpose");
            context.Wait(Getuserpurpose);

        }
        public async Task Getuserpurpose(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            var message = await argument;
            this.Purpose = message.Text;
            await context.PostAsync("Now please tell me the client name");
            context.Wait(Getuserclient);

        }

        private async Task Getuserclient(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var message = await result;
            ClientName = message.Text;
            await context.PostAsync("Now please tell me Team Name");
            context.Wait(GetUserTeamName);
        }

        private async Task GetUserTeamName(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var message = await result;
            Teamname = message.Text;
            await context.PostAsync("Got it");
            context.Done(this);
        }
    }
```